# How to insert HashMap into PostgreSQL as JSON type?

Tags: postgresql, rust

`contacts` has a data structure as `HashMap`, I'm using `PostgreSQL` client -[rust-postgres](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres) to insert `contact`'s key and value into a table, then I want to select from the table. Below is what I tried so far. I need help with writing the right syntax.

```
use postgres::{Client, NoTls};
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut client = Client::connect("host=127.0.0.1 user=postgres", NoTls)?;

    client.simple_query("
        DROP TABLE 
        IF EXISTS following_relation;
        ")?;

    client.simple_query("
        CREATE TABLE following_relation (
            id               SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            relation         JSON NOT NULL
        )
    ")?;

    let mut contacts = HashMap::new();
    let mut v: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

    v = vec!["jump".to_owned(), "jog".to_string()];
    contacts.insert("Ashley", v.clone());

    for (name, hobby) in contacts.iter() {
        // 1. How to write sql statement with parameters?
        client.execute(
        "INSERT INTO following_relation(relation) 
         VALUE ('{"name" : $1, "hobby" : $2}')", 
        &[&name, &hobby],
    )?;  
    }

    for row in client.query("SELECT id, relation FROM following_relation", &[])? {
        // 2. How to read from parse the result?
        let id: i32 = row.get(0);
        let relation = row.get(1);
        //println!("found person: {} {} {:?}", id, relation["name"], relation["hobby"]); 
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

I've been given the hints

> 1. Like the error message says, your query has VALUE but it needs to be VALUES.
> 2. Query parameters cannot be interpolated into strings. You should build the object in Rust, and use https://docs.rs/postgres/0.17.0/postgres/types/struct.Json.html to wrap the types when inserting.

I have no idea how to apply `pub struct Json<T>(pub T);` here.

How to build the `query` required in function [`execute`](https://docs.rs/postgres/0.17.0/postgres/struct.Client.html#method.execute)?

```
pub fn execute<T: ?Sized>(
    &mut self,
    query: &T,
    params: &[&(dyn ToSql + Sync)]
) -> Result<u64, Error>
where
    T: ToStatement,
```

---

UPDATED, I tried with a more brief code sample

```
use postgres::{Client, NoTls};
use postgres::types::Json;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct relations {
    name : String,
    hobby: Vec<String>
}
pub struct Json<T>(pub T);

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut client = Client::connect("host=127.0.0.1 user=postgres", NoTls)?;

    client.simple_query("
        DROP TABLE 
        IF EXISTS following_relation;

        ")?;

    client.simple_query("
        CREATE TABLE following_relation (
            id      SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            relation    JSON NOT NULL
        )
    ")?;

    let rel = relations {
        name: "czfzdxx".to_string(),
        hobby: vec![
            "basketball".to_string(),
            "jogging".to_string()
        ],
    };

    client.execute(
        r#"INSERT INTO following_relation(relation)
             VALUE ($1)"#,
        &[&Json(&rel)]
    )?;

    Ok(())
}
```

I get

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `postgres::types::Json`
```

Comment: I couldnt make it work, here's what I got so maybe you can pick up from there

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pbn4/ea14f0ca0a25fb376523ab850327abfb

Comment: Also the cargo.toml https://gist.github.com/pbn4/5b6dadc9ca31e2aed91b3a391ecd2b98

Comment: @pbn I will take a look immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is `main.rs`:

```
use postgres::{Client, NoTls};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use postgres_types::Json;
use postgres_types::{FromSql};


#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, FromSql)]
struct Relation {
    name : String,
    hobby: Vec<String>
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut client = Client::connect("host=127.0.0.1 user=postgres", NoTls)?;

    client.simple_query("
        DROP TABLE 
        IF EXISTS following_relation;

        ")?;

    client.simple_query("
        CREATE TABLE following_relation (
            id      SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            relation    JSON NOT NULL
        )
    ")?;

    let rel = Relation {
        name: "czfzdxx".to_string(),
        hobby: vec![
            "basketball".to_string(),
            "jogging".to_string()
        ],
    };

    client.execute(
        "INSERT INTO following_relation (relation) VALUES ($1)",
        &[&Json::<Relation>(rel)]
    )?;

    for row in &client.query("SELECT relation FROM following_relation", &[]).unwrap() {
        let rel: Json<Relation> = row.get(0);
        println!("{:?}", rel);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

and `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "testapp"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
postgres = {version = "0.17.0"}
tokio-postgres = "0.5.1"
serde = {version = "1.0.104", features = ["derive"]}
postgres-types = {version = "0.1.0", features = ["derive", "with-serde_json-1"]}
serde_json = "1.0.45"
```

And here is the relevant documentation used: [postgres_types](https://docs.rs/postgres-types/0.1.0/postgres_types/trait.ToSql.html) and [postgres](https://docs.rs/postgres/0.17.0/postgres/). Search for `serde_json`, `ToSql` and `FromSql` traits are implemented for this third-party type.

Comment: Could you add the code for parsing the result of `client.query("SELECT relation FROM following_relation", &[])?`

Comment: Suprisingly it is not straight forward. I found [this](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres/issues/441)

Comment: Try with using serde_json::Value instead Json from postgres.

Comment: I just edited the code. See if it works for you. Copy paste the entire things because  i changed type names too to remove warnings.

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon Sorry for saying that I would take a look at it in evening, I simply forgot.

Answer (score 5):

You want Rust [raw string literal](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#raw-string-literals):

```rust
for (name, hobby) in contacts.iter() {
    client.execute(
        r#"INSERT INTO following_relation(relation) 
           VALUE ('{"name" : ($1), "hobby" : ($2)}')"#,
        &[&name, &following],
    )?;
}
```

Between the start `r#"` and the end `"#`, your string literals can have any character except `#` itself without escaping. If you also want `#` itself, then starts the raw string literals with multiple `#`s and ends with matching number of `#`s.